# How to convert string of format "29MAY2018" to date in access query

Tags: date, ms-access

I have a column that has values like this "29MAY2018" i.;e of ddMMMyyyy format. How can I convert this to date type and find difference of two dates? Please kindly give me code to do this in Access Query

Comment: You need to create a public function in the standard VBA module, which converts the string with date to date data type

Answer (score 2):

You can use *Format* for this:

```
TrueDate = CDate(Format(TextDate, "@@ @@@ @@@@"))
```

In the GUI:

```
TrueDate: CDate(Format([TextDateField],"@@ @@@ @@@@"))
```

Comment: Clever use of `Format`. This solution is dependent on Access running on an English locale, however.

Comment: @ErikvonAsmuth: Yes, any method reading month names or abbreviations using CDate or DateValue will require these the text to match the localisation.